# Spring - Angular - Adding Dynamic Content

Tags: angular, spring

I just started using Spring and Angular and was following this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

I reached the point "Adding dynamic content" and couldn't get any further. When I use the below code I always get the error that the attributes *id* and *content* of the object *greeting* are unresolved. How can I fix that?

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Id: <span>{{greeting.id}}</span></p>
    <p>Message: <span>{{greeting.content}}!</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Demo';
  greeting = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

  @RequestMapping("/resource")
  public Map<String,Object> home() {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Regards

Comment: In your browser developer tools there should be a network tab. Open the network tab and reload the page. That should show if if it is sending the request to backend and what it is receiving as response.

Comment: try this: `greeting: any = {};`. this line will tell the typescript compiler to skip type shecks for "greeting" field, and the error should be gone

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Andrei in the comments `greeting: any = {}` fixes the problem.
"This line will tell the typescript compiler to skip type checks for "greeting" field, and the error should be gone" - Andrei